# What Invokes and distinguishes "It", "Because" and "Establish"

Tags: c#, mspec

I've started using MSpec recently, breaking classes into, `Establish`, `Because` and, `It`.

Although I know how to use them, I'm not sure what goes into making them work.

I know they are delegates

```
Because of = () =>
{

};
```

But when looking at how delegates are defined:

```
public delegate void Print(int value);
```

It looks like `Establish`, `Because` and, `It` are defined as delegates that return nothing (`void`) and take no arguments.

Which makes sense, but how are `Establish`, `Because` and, `It` distinguished from each other. I.e. What stops using `It` instead of `Establish` working just the same. And how does one of them know to use the other? i.e. `It` uses `Establish`

Also they just get put in the class. What Invokes them?

```
public class foobar: setup
{
    private static int engineId;

    Because of = () =>
    {

    };

    It should = () =>
    {

    };
}
```

See the above has the delegates initialized to these functions. But I don't know how they get called and why this isn't okay:

```
public class foobar: setup
{
    private static int engineId;

    It of = () =>
    {

    };

    It should = () =>
    {

    };
}
```

Can anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: Have you looked at the definitions? What, *specifically* is unclear to you about those definitions?

Comment: oh, yeah sorry, They are delegates. But that still leaves the question about how they are distinguished and use each other. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those delegates are of different types, even though they all have the same signature. So they are distinguished based on their type. For example suppose you have this class from example usage:

```
[Subject("Authentication")]
public class When_authenticating_a_user
{
    Establish context = () =>
    {
        Subject = new SecurityService();
    };

    Cleanup after = () =>
    {
        Subject.Dispose();
    };

    static SecurityService Subject;
}
```

And now you want to imitate running that test. You use reflection to get all fields first, because both `context` and `after` are fields:

```
var fields = typeof(When_authenticating_a_user).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Now you have bunch of fields, but which is which? You can distinguish them by field type. One is of type `Establish` and another is of type `Cleanup` (both are delegate types with the same signature):

```
var establish = fields.FirstOrDefault(c => c.FieldType == typeof(Establish));
var cleanup = fields.FirstOrDefault(c => c.FieldType == typeof(Cleanup));
```

And then you create an instance and execute them according to some logic:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(When_authenticating_a_user));
// get method
var establishMethod = (Establish)establish.GetValue(instance);
// execute
establishMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're delegates, [as declared here](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/blob/master/Source/Machine.Specifications/Framework.cs):

They're all parameterless void delegates, which are distinguished from each other in terms of how they're *used* in the framework. A method that accepts an `It` won't accept an `Establish` for example, so that indicated what the intention of the method is. Different delegates really are different types, even if they have the same signature. (You *can* create one delegate to wrap an instance of a different delegate type with a compatible signature, but that's relatively rare.)

I'm not saying I particularly like the framework or the names chosen, but having different delegates which happen to have the same signature makes perfect sense in terms of expressing the different intended meanings for those delegates.